# What is an alternative to aloe vera gel for making your own hand sanitizer?

Tags: cleaning, health

I have seen a few articles describing how to make your own hand sanitizer (such as [this](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/hand-sanitizer-coronavirus-make-your-own/)). Two ingredients are required - isopropyl alcohol and aloe vera gel. I have isopropyl alcohol, but do not have any aloe vera gel, and it seems everywhere is out of stock of both ingredients.

Is there any alternative to aloe vera gel for making your own hand sanitizer?

Comment: Do you have the minimum suggested 90% stock solution so that when mixed it will have minimum 70% alcohol content to be an effective disinfectant?

Comment: I do have 99.9% isopropyl alcohol.

Answer (score 4):

**Hand Sanitizer Hack**

According to all current information available on the subject of asepsis, the best alternative to using an alcohol-based hand sanitizer is to wash your hands* using soap and clean, preferably warm, running water for a minimum time of 20 seconds.

*Palms, back, fingers, nails, cuticles, etc. including wrist.

Links are many so they are not included. Search "hand-washing" asepsis, or any term used in this answer.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, hand sanitizers are not a substitute for hand washing, but a viable alternative for the cases when plain old water and soap aren’t available, according to various official recommendations.

Comment: Skin specialists (dermatologists) tell us that hand sanitizers (Purelle™ was mentioned specifically) are less damaging to our skin that the currently recommended washing routine. Avoid over washing to preserve your skin oils. Split fingernails (lengthwise) are an indication of skin damage due to over washing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it, as long as you include an emollient to keep your skin feeling good. The [WHO formulation](https://www.who.int/gpsc/5may/Guide_to_Local_Production.pdf) suggests glycerin, which is known not to hamper the effectiveness of the formula. Thickeners are not needed, and may cause people to use less product. You want your hands to be really wet!

Another alternative is to dilute your alcohol to the appropriate ratio, skip the emollient and use moisturizer after you sanitize.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is the plant itself. Buy an aloe vera plant, cut off some of the leaves and scoop out the fleshy insides. You may want to put it through a sieve. Aloe vera gel usually consists of 98% aloe, the rest of the ingredients are probably not gonna make a huge difference with the amount of alcohol the recipe requires.

I have a plant that we use for mild burns, insect bites and so on. I just cut off a tiny piece of a leaf and rub the flesh against my skin. Be aware, though. Aloe vera is toxic in large doses and should not be consumed, as is with most any skin remedy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

witch hazel as an alternative, the consistency of your sanitizer will be more like a spray.

Answer (score 0):

Aquasonic ultrasound gel. I don't know why no one answered the question. Yeah it's pretty clear to everyone that washing your hands is the best way to stay sanitary. But hand sanitizer has its purpose especially when you're not around a sink. Hence the reason are medical facilities are filled with them. I rely on both methods due to my occupation and the need to do my part to keep my family and this economy going. One part Aquasonic gel two parts denatured alcohol. I will deal with dry cracked hands if I have to.